# MASM assembly language(x86) macros (CBW,LOOP, PTR)

Tags: loops, pointers, macros, masm

Suppose your assembler does not have the operations CBW, LOOP and PTR, how can you design a macro for each of theses?

Example:

```
    MCBW macro
    move AX,0
    div AX,CH
    endm
```

Comment: `CBW` and `LOOP` have been part of the x86 ever since the 8086 AFAIK. Why would you use an assembler that doesn't support them? Does such an assembler even exist?

Comment: It was an exam question.

Answer (score 0):

Loop macro:

```
;//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
myLoop MACRO myLabel:REQ
;//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    dec ecx
    jnz myLabel

ENDM
```

in proc example:

```
mov ecx, 5
mov eax, 0
ANY_LOOP:
   inc eax
myLoop ANY_LOOP
```

CBW macro:

```
;//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
myCBW MACRO
;//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov ebx, eax
    and eax, 080h
    shl ax, 1
    xchg ah, al
    mov ecx, 0FFFFh
    mul ecx
    mov al, bl

ENDM
```

in proc example:

```
mov eax, 8Fh
myCBW
```

PTR macro:

```
;//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
myPointer MACRO source:REQ
;//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    exitm <[source]>

ENDM
```

in proc example:

```
.data
    number  DWORD 5

.code
    main PROC

    mov eax, myPointer(number)
```